# Design: Abstracting JDBC and datasource to SQL/DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, mysql, design-patterns, jdbc

My back-end calls for a dynamic datasource and topology, and my front-end calls for a bunch of app coding that queries the RDBMS.  My idea is to walk away from the JDBC API altogether, as it turns out, for any API the app coding couples itself to.

Here's the design idea... On queries, the app code passes in SQL, and receives DefaultTableModel as a result.  On updates, the app code passes in SQL (even batches of it), and receives success/failure code (plus error message) as a result.

<s>Would you couple all of your app code to class DefaultTableModel?  Would there be a better class for generic, decoupled query result handling? (If I ever need metadata, I can subclass/encapsulate that in with the result) Are there examples out there of this already being done?  I do not need more than the above for this application.  I don't have extravagant RDBMS needs.</s>

What standard non-JDBC options does the Java API have for holding the kind of data in a ResultSet?  I am aware of AbstractTableModel and DefaultTableModel. In any event, it has to be smart enough to associate a class with each column in terms of datatype.

Comment: `JTable` is a graphical component. It's an odd choice to return data.

Comment: It would seem backwards for the (front-end) app to be SQL-aware and the back-end to return back `JTables`. Could you clarify your intentions further?

Comment: What's less graphical than a JTable?  OH, maybe defaultTableModel.  Mick, the front end is table and column aware, and might as well be SQL aware.  I don't see a need for (in this case) for it to be JDBC aware.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. Proper design would dictate that the frontend doesn't care about the backend (and vice versa), but receives well formed data. This can be actual domain objects, or some general `Collection` types if the data is not typed. Passing SQL anywhere is a bad idea.

Comment: But aren't tables at the domain level?  SQL is, after all, 4th-GL stuff.  But not JDBC.